# SQL Server Recursive CTE Many-to-Many "Best Match"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I've got a many-to-many relationship.  I want to identify the best matches.

A match = `@firstParty.StartDate` between `@thirdParty.MatchRangeStart` and `@thirdParty.MatchRangeEnd`.

best match = the earliest record in `@thirdParty` that's not a "best match" for an earlier record in `@firstParty`.

I can't use a loop, for performance reasons.  So, I think a recursive CTE will be needed.

Here's my desired output:

```
FirstPartyId StartDate  ThirdPartyId ThirdPartyStartDate
------------ ---------- ------------ -------------------
1            2016-01-01 1            2016-01-10
2            2016-01-02 2            2016-01-11
3            2016-01-03 3            2016-01-12
```

Script:

```
declare @firstParty table
(
    FirstPartyId integer identity,
    StartDate date,
    ThirdPartyId integer
);

insert into @firstParty (StartDate)
values
('01/01/2016'), ('01/02/2016'), ('01/03/2016'), ('01/04/2017'), ('01/05/2017');

/*
dates in @firstParty and @thirdParty are not guaranteed to be unique 
in all scenarios
*/

declare @thirdParty table
(
    ThirdPartyId integer identity,
    StartDate date,
    MatchRangeStart date,
    MatchRangeEnd date
);

insert into @thirdParty (StartDate)
values
('01/10/2016'), ('01/11/2016'), ('01/12/2016');


update @thirdParty set MatchRangeStart = dateadd(d, -31, StartDate), MatchRangeEnd = dateadd(d, 31, StartDate);

declare @matches table 
(
    Id integer identity,
    FirstPartyId integer,
    FirstPartyStartDate date,
    ThirdPartyId integer,
    ThirdPartyStartDate date
);

insert into @matches (FirstPartyId, FirstPartyStartDate, ThirdPartyId, ThirdPartyStartDate)
select
    fp.FirstPartyId,
    fp.StartDate,
    tp.ThirdPartyId,
    tp.StartDate
from
    @thirdParty tp
    join @firstParty fp on
        fp.StartDate between tp.MatchRangeStart and tp.MatchRangeEnd
        ;




select
    fp.FirstPartyId,
    fp.StartDate,
    tpm.ThirdPartyId,
    tpm.ThirdPartyStartDate 
from
    @firstParty fp
    cross apply
    (
        select top 1
            m.*
        from
            @matches m
        where
            fp.FirstPartyId = m.FirstPartyId
        order by
            m.ThirdPartyStartDate
    ) tpm;
```

Comment: What order of magnitude are we talking about here? If it's millions of rows, then I would suggest a loop without any transactions.

Comment: About 500 records in either table would be the most.  I'm currently using a loop (no transaction) and running into performance issues.

Comment: It turns out that the performance issues were not related to the loop.  So, I am sticking with the loop for now.  I'll leave this question as unanswered in case someone can come up with a brilliant recursive CTE.

Comment: The short version of why CTE is unsuitable here: it was designed to handle hierarchical data with predictably few nesting levels, while yours is sequential. Which requires straightforward (i.e. non-recursive) approach, but the queries will be quite complicated and will probably involve a few cartesians. I think I could do that, but it would require about a week of dedicated effort.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  Definitely not worth the effort in this case!